# How to add aggregated rows based on other rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
index a b c d
    0 1 1 1 3
    1 1 1 2 1
    2 1 2 1 4
    3 1 2 2 1
    4 2 2 1 5
    5 2 2 2 9
    6 2 2 1 2
    7 2 3 2 6
```

I want to add new rows where `c` is 0, and `d` is replaced with the maximum value of `d` of existing rows where `a` and `b` are the same:

```
index a b c d
    8 1 1 0 3
    9 1 2 0 4
   10 2 2 0 9
   11 2 3 0 6
```

What command can I use? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? what hasn't worked for you? can you post your sample code.

Comment: Very new at Pandas (inherited someone's code), so don't know how to start. I looked at pandas.DataFrame.aggregate, but it adds a row of aggregates of all the columns, instead of matching those with the same `a` and `b` values.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you can using `sort_values` chain with `drop_duplicates`, then `append`

```
df.append(df.sort_values('d').drop_duplicates(['a','b'],keep='last').assign(c=0))
Out[77]: 
       a  b  c  d
index            
0      1  1  1  3
1      1  1  2  1
2      1  2  1  4
3      1  2  2  1
4      2  2  1  5
5      2  2  2  9
6      2  2  1  2
7      2  3  2  6
0      1  1  0  3
2      1  2  0  4
7      2  3  0  6
5      2  2  0  9
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @WeNYoBen. If there are many more columns than `a` and `b`, can I put in drop_duplicates([ ]) something that says "everything except `index`, `c` and `d`"?

Comment: @Gnubie do like `drop_duplicates(df.columns.difference(['c','d']).tolist())`

Comment: @WeNYoBen: a nice one!. +1

Answer (score 2):

I come up with solution using `groupby` and `pd.concat` as follows:

```
pd.concat([df, df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['d'].max().reset_index().assign(c=0)], ignore_index=True)


Out[1668]:
    a  b  c  d
0   1  1  1  3
1   1  1  2  1
2   1  2  1  4
3   1  2  2  1
4   2  2  1  5
5   2  2  2  9
6   2  2  1  2
7   2  3  2  6
8   1  1  0  3
9   1  2  0  4
10  2  2  0  9
11  2  3  0  6
```